# MySQL: Count rows with similar not duplicated content as one

Tags: mysql

I am working with Codeigniter and its Query Builder class where I have a table with IDs and names. 
Those names look like 1234_1a or 2345_2a where 1a can be 1b or 2a,2b,3a... and so on.
Now I want to count all these "1234" and "2345" but write them as one type.

So far I tried with:

```
$this->db->like('names', '1a', 'before');
$this->db->or_like('names', '1b', 'before');
return $this->db->count_all_results('table');
```

But the problem: 
What if there is 3456_2a but no 3456_1a, than it doesn't work anymore...

```
id  name
2   1212_1a
3   1243_1a
7   3142_1a
24  1243_2a
30  3142_2b
80  2315_2b
136 1243_3b
512 8562_1a
```

This is how I would like it:

```
Result:
name    count
1212    1
1243    1
3142    1
2315    1
8562    1
```

Answer (score 0):

If we always want to return a `count` value of 1, when the count of the number of rows in more than 1 ... then we aren't really returning a count.

And what is the pattern of the names... do they end with a digit and a letter, or is that underscore character important too?

What is to be done with name values such as `12345a` or `5678_b2` or `11_22_3b`? How are those to be handled?

Seems to me like we want to use a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.name,'_',1)  AS `foo`
     , 1                              AS `count`
  FROM ( 
         SELECT 2 AS `id`, '1212_1a' AS `name`
         UNION ALL SELECT 3, '1243_1a'
         UNION ALL SELECT 7, '3142_1a'
         UNION ALL SELECT 24, '1243_2a'
         UNION ALL SELECT 30, '3142_2b'
         UNION ALL SELECT 80, '2315_2b'
         UNION ALL SELECT 136, '1243_3b'
         UNION ALL SELECT 512, '8562_1a'
       ) t
 GROUP BY `foo`
 ORDER BY `foo`
```

The inline view (derived table) is in the query for testing. Replace that with the table reference:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.name,'_',1)  AS `foo`
     , 1                              AS `count`
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP BY `foo`
 ORDER BY `foo`
```

The expression for `foo` may need to be adjusted, to get desirable behavior with values that don't follow the regular pattern. Consider name values with no underscore, with more than one underscore, with endings other than a digit.  We could also include a `WHERE`  clause to exclude rows that don't follow the pattern,

```
WHERE t.name REGEXP '_[0-9][a-z]$'
```

(only `name` values that end with underscore, digit, lowercase letter).

Without a tested SQL query, I wouldn't know what to implement in CodeIgniter Query Builder.